# Python: Define dynamic extension methods based on their arguments

Tags: python

Suppose I have following methods:

```python
from torch import device

def run_cuda(device:device, count:int):
    ...

def gen_noise(device:device, width:int, height:int):
    ...
```

If I were to call these, I have to:

```python
device = DEVICE

run_cuda(device, count=8)
gen_noise(device, width=128, height=128)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to somehow remove multiple `device` argument in some way for better readabiliy. So I'd rather:

```python
device = DEVICE

def use_device(device:device):
    ...

# multiline
device_user = use_device(device)
device_user.run_cuda(count=8)
device_user.gen_noise(width=128, height=128)

# inline
use_device(device).run_cuda(count=8)
use_device(device).gen_noise(width=128, height=128)
```

obviously I could simply wrap `device` class and manually define methods in it. But It feels like it would be quite better to define simple `use_device(device)` function that takes `device` argument, and pass into following function by 'calling' it.

Maybe something like so:

```python
def use_device(device:device):
    # call arbitrary methods that has 'device' argument.
    return ExtensionMethodLikeCallable[[device, *args, **kwargs],any]()
```

Is this possible in Python?

Thank you.

---

Edit:

Justification for this implementation could be the fact that I could then:

```python
use_device(device).use_dimension(512,512).use_iteration(8).gen_noise()
```

instead of:

```python
gen_noise(device=device, width=512, height=512, iteration=8)
```

which one has 'better' readability is admittedly arguable but let's say it's just my personal preference.

Comment: Since it is the first argument, you can just pass `device` instead of `device=device`.

Comment: If those two functions must have the `device` argument supplied, then I know of no way to call those functions without that argument and somehow have it suppled automatically.  However, you can probably define your own versions of those functions at that same level, and have your versions call the originals.  So then you could have the behavior you want, having your versions add the `device` argument for you.  I like the Fluent style that you show.  That would be easy to build yourself.

Comment: @TimRoberts Good call! Edited the question.

Comment: @CryptoFool Hmm. That's the only way then, I guess. Currently I have quite a number of functions with device argument so I think it's not feasible to do all that manually. Maybe some sort of builder pattern might do. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @CC-white - in actuality, pretty much everything/anything is possible with Python.  If you really had tons of functions that all had this same signature, I assume that it wouldn't be too difficult to use introspection to search in the namespace/class that has those functions/methods, find them, and then monkey-patch them or (probably more appropriately) build up a wrapper for them programatically.  Are they all members of a class?  If so, you could build a dynamic subclass of that class that had all of the same methods, but your versions supply the `device` argument if it isn't supplied...

Comment: ...or maybe you could intercept the look-ups of each method or call of each method (don't know how to do the latter) and do a just-in-time patching of some sort.  Another thing you might do is dynamically add a decorator to each method.  Lots of possiblities with Python.  If you want this API badly enough, and if there really are too many methods to use the brute-force approach, I would think there has to be a pretty clean way to build what you want with introspection.  Sounds like fun :)

Comment: @CryptoFool Great info. As you've mentioned, after some digging I've noticed Python is indeed capable of virtually any kind of tweaks if I try hard enough. As a long time rigid .Net developer it was something that I've never thought of. But personally I don't like monkey patching for it might eventually break IDE intellisense in some way, especially autocomplete. So maybe with some minimal brute-forces involved I could find a middle ground solution. I'll post my conclusion in the future if you are interested. Thank you for the help!